# Find the current line in a Rich Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a rich text box where you can edit java code with a listbox on the side of it that has the line numbers. I want the listbox to scroll with the rich text box so that they line up. How would you get them to scroll as one?

Answer (score 3):

There is an MSDN entry on the [GetLineFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex.aspx) method on a [RichTextBoxControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

This in conjunction with the [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) property should allow you to do something like this:

```
//This next line only indicates the caret position if no text is selected
Int32 caretPosition = richTextBox1.SelectionStart

Int32 lineNum = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(caretPosition)
```

Comment: When i typed in the vb declaration it said that it could not be declared overrides because it does not override a function in a base class

Comment: I'm a little confused... were you trying to implement that member, or just use it. It is a member of RichTextBox, so you should be able to just call it on the instance of your RichTextBox control you are trying to use.

Comment: I have a rich text box where you can edit java code with a listbox on the side of it that has the line numbers. I want the listbox to scroll with the rich text box so that they line up. I just figured that getting the line number and setting the listbox's selectedindex to it would work. If you have another sugestion that would be great